# Errors on "npm run dev" (after Laravel clean install)

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I'm very excited to learn Laravel and create a webapp based on a bootstrap template I bought (OneUI). I successfully installed Laravel (the /public route returns the default view to my browser correctly). Now i'm following the install guide of the template, and i'm experiencing problems with npm commands that return errors that I can't understand (I'm not familiar with npm).

I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me to find what's wrong so I could finally using Laravel with the Templates.

As requested in the OneUI documentation, i copy the public & resources folders, the routes/web.php file, and the webpack.mix.js file. Then, i install the npm dependencies running the following command :

```
npm i browser-sync browser-sync-webpack-plugin sass sass-loader bootstrap@^4.5.3 jquery@^3.5.1 jquery-scroll-lock@^3.1.3 jquery.appear@^1.0.1 js-cookie@^2.2.1 popper.js@^1.16.1 simplebar@^5.3.0 -D
```

This seems to run OK with a few warnings about some deprecated packages.
Then i run :

```
npm run dev
```

I get this return :

```
> @ dev /volume1/web/dev/myproject
> npm run development


> @ development /volume1/web/dev/myproject
> mix

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npx ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npx',
  path: 'npx',
  spawnargs: [
    'webpack',
    '--progress',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/services/homes/admin/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T22_32_54_150Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/services/homes/admin/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T22_32_54_340Z-debug.log
```

This is on Linux, directly on my Synology (I don't use anything like a VM/Docker).
To install Laravel, I simply did this :

1. Installed php7.4 + libraries
2. Installed composer
3. Went into my web folder and entered the command : `composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject`
4. Added write access to my http user on the storage folder

I tryied this already without success :

1. As advised on other websites:
   rm -rf node_modules
   rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
   npm cache clear --force
   npm install
   npm run dev
2. I tryied to do a npm install and npm run dev on a clean Laravel Install (before the install of all the packages required by the OneUI templates) to try to see if it's related to the OneUI files or the npm dependencies I installed. I have the same errors. So I understand it's not related to the OneUI install, but an issue with npm / my Laravel files (?).

In advance, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Seems like it wants `npx` globally installed

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ohgodwhy !
Your answer is useful. I didn't get that in the Error message, but it makes sense as ENOENT seems to mean there's no such file / directory.

But should I install npm packages globally ? (Is it a best practice ?).
My understanding is local installs are better. Do you know if there's something i could do to fix this issue without a global install ? (a path I'd need to change somewhere in the code maybe ?).

Thank you.

Comment: it might make sense to install it globally for your project, it might not. it totally depends on the use case. i would say for the most part installing it globally would make sense for that particular package